# How can I count all files in a directory with PHP? (e.g. 124 Files)

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how I can count all of my XML files in one directory. How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Just wondering, what did you try codewise, or search for before you posted this? Found a possible answer within five seconds in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$count = 0;

foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;  //gives you the file name
    $count++;
}

echo $count;
```

or per MitMaro, simply just get the # of xml files without accessing file information:

```
echo count(glob("*.xml"));
```

Comment: Any reason you did not use `count(glob('*.xml'))`?

Comment: i want to show how he can retrive the individual file name as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
$dir = "random_directory/";
$files = glob("$dir*.xml");
$count = $files !== false ? count($files) : 0;
echo $count;
```

Just change $dir to your directory.

Comment: So if there's any XML files in the dir, count how many JPGs are in there? hruh?

Comment: Pretty much matched the one that I found, outside it counting jpgs instead of xml :)

Comment: ? I've had this code for ages(or at least as long as I can remember). I just found it in one of my many files on my HD. The only difference is I had it count the number of .html files.

Comment: @Mike: yeah, plus it was calling glob() twice.  I don't unnecessary unnecessary code repetition.

Comment: Could turn the whole thing into a one-liner: `echo ($files = glob('random_directory/*.xml')) !== false ? count($files) : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = scandir('/path/to/dir/');
$count = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (strtolower(substr($file, 4)) == '.xml') {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/scandir

http://php.net/substr